# Matlab vectorize for loop (grid depends on loop index)

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vectorization

I have to do a maximization of a 3-D array V(e,b,d) over the first-dimension, obtaining something that I call e_opt which will be a b*d matrix, i.e.

**e_opt(b,d) = argmax_e {V(e,b,d)}**

The non-standard feature is that the grid for e depends on d. So I am not able to eliminate the loop over d and I need to speed up the code. I attach a MWE so that things become clear. On my PC it runs in about 1 secs but this is too slow since I have to do this many times.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
clear
close all
clc
rng("default")

% Size of grids
n_b = 1000;
n_d = 1000;
n_e = 5000;

% Parameters
delta   = 0.2696037674949296; 
%omega_0 = 0.0015534835229589;
%omega_1 = 0.0013023827114628;

% Generate fake data
cost_mat = rand(n_e,n_d);
prob_mat = rand(n_e,n_d);
option_nob = rand(n_b,1);
d_grid = linspace(0,2.3,n_d)';

%% Create a grid for "e". The non-standard feature is that the upper bound
% of the e_grid depends on "d"
e_grid_mat = zeros(n_e,n_d);
e_min = 0;
space = 1.5;
for d_c=1:n_d
    d_val = d_grid(d_c);
    e_max = 0.1+0.2*d_val; %silly example, don't take this literally
    % e_grid is NOT equally spaced
    e_grid_mat(:,d_c) = e_min+(e_max-e_min)*(linspace(0,1,n_e).^space)';
end

%% The code below is the part that I'd like to speed up
tic
e_opt = zeros(n_b,n_d);
for d_c = 1:n_d
    % Effort grid depends on d (upper bound changes, but same no. of elements)
    e_grid = e_grid_mat(:,d_c); %each column of e_grid_mat is different!
    % V(e,b) has dim: (n_e,n_b) and I maximize with respect to the first dimension, e
    V = -cost_mat(:,d_c)-delta*prob_mat(:,d_c).*option_nob';
    [~,max_ind] = max(V,[],1); %maxind is (1,n_b) vector
    e_opt(:,d_c)  = e_grid(max_ind);
end %end d
toc

%To check results
disp(mean(mean(e_opt)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the range of values of `e` depends on `d` does not prevent computing the *index* of the maximizing `e` in a vectorized way. The non-uniformity of the grid only has an effect when retrieving the maximizing *values* of `e` from their indices; but this can be done quite easily using [linear indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/02/08/linear-indexing/).

Thus, the last part of your code becomes

```
V = -cost_mat-delta*prob_mat.*reshape(option_nob, 1, 1, []); % compute the full V
[~, max_ind] = max(V, [], 1); % indices of maxima along the first dimension
max_ind = permute(max_ind, [2 3 1]); % remove first dimension, which is a singleton
max_ind = max_ind + (0:size(V,2)-1).'*size(V,1); % apply linear indexing
e_opt = e_grid_mat(max_ind).'; % retrieve maximizing values
```

The code is now vectorized, but take into account that this does not always lead to a significant speed-up.

Comment: Thanks! But in line 4 of your code should it be 0:size(V,2) or 1:size(V,2) ?

Comment: @Alessandro Why do you think it should be `1`? I did try my code and your code, and they give the same `e_opt`. If you are confused because Matlab indexing is 1-based, not that the `0:size(V,2):...` part is added to `max_ind` as computed from the previous line, and so the resulting linear index will always start at `1`. For a more specific example, lets' say you have a 3x4 matrix you want to linearly index into: `A = rand(3,4), ind = (1:size(A,1)).' + (0:size(A,1):numel(A)-1); isequal(A, A(ind))`. I hope that makes it clear that the `0`  is correct

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Is there a way to do the same using ind2sub?

Comment: @Alessandro More or less, yes. My line 4 is essentially what `sub2ind` (not `ind2sub`) would do. I've developed a habit of avoiding `sub2ind`. I find it easier and clearer to do it manually. And it's probably a little faster, because `sub2ind` internally has to do that same operation, plus input argument checking, and there's also the overhead due to function call

Comment: Perfect, now I understand! Your example with the matrix can actually be also written as ind = sub2ind(size(A),repmat(1:size(A,1),1,2),repmat(1:size(A,2),3,1)  )

Comment: I tested the code and unfortunately the vectorized version is slower than the loop-based version. In any case, I learnt something new about linear indexing in Matlab, so many thanks to you, @luis

Comment: @Alessandro Glad I could help at least with that! Part of the problem with the vectorized version is that it requires much more memory, which can slow things down if the system needs to use virtual memory